# Any easy way to subset my consecutive data?

Tags: r, subset

One of my data attributes is "Time",from o seconds to 8640 seconds (consecutive), my professor ask me to analysis my data (0-5 mins) (5-10 mins) (10 -15 mins) separately. I know the basic code to subset my data, like:

```
data<-data[which(data$Time<=300&data$>=0),]
```

But if I do in this way, I have to repeat again again and again... I am thinking, can I have an easy way to solve this problem? Anyone can help me? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Check out the `cut()` command.

Comment: Thank you, but after "c1 <- cut(n2f1$Time.Elapsed,seq(0, 4560, by = 300))", I got atomic vectors. How can I use the sub dataset to do analysis separately?

Comment: Do it in a loop: i in 1 to (8640/60)/5{ tmp_data<-data[which(data$Time<=300*i&data$>=300*(i-1)),]}

Comment: @JJFord3 Loops are *very* unhealthy in `R`, which works by vectorised assignments: see my answer below.

Comment: @Ian Once you have the cut, you can use `split()` to create separate data.frames for each chunk. Or use that as a factor variable in analysis.

Comment: @MrFlick `split` creates a list of vectors containing the split data frames. In order to access all of them one should anyway either refer to each one singularly, or loop through all (which is discouraged); one should instead be able to group by the `cut()` directly, as vectorised assignment.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco there's nothing wrong with a well written loop (although they are usually not necessary). You could easily sapply over this list. It all depends on what you need to do down stream. Some analyses require separate subsets. Others can use a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that your data set is as following, without loss of generality:

```
time <- seq(0,8640)
```

define your unit blocks of time as (you are looking at units of 5 minutes)

```
blocks <- seq(1, length(time), 300)
```

and then

```
groups <- cbind(time, cut(time, blocks))
```

accompanies each row in `time` with the corresponding block of 5 minutes (variable `V2`) it corresponds to. In fact:

```
R: set.seed(1234)
R: groups[sample(nrow(groups), 5), ]
     time V2
983   983  4
5377 5377 18
5263 5263 18
5385 5385 18
7435 7435 25
```

Once so, you can perform any sort of operation of your data set grouping by the variable `V2`.

Comment: I stuck here: blocks <- seq(0, 4560, 300)
groups <- cbind(n2f1$Time.Elapsed, cut(n2f1$Time.Elapsed, blocks))
groups[sample(nrow(groups), 1), ]

Comment: My data name is "n2f1", I am using two variables, one is "Time.Elapsed"; the other one is "step length"... I wanna analysis step length under different time interval... I know your answer seems very clear already,, but I still get confused how can I use it...

Comment: > groups[n2f1(nrow(groups), 5), ]
Error: could not find function "n2f1"

Comment: @Ian As I said, once you have attached you new variable to your existing data frame (with `cbind` or anything else of that sort) you can just perform any analysis you want grouping by the new introduced variable, which distinguishes between different subsets of time intervals. How to perform operations on data frames grouping by variables is then another kind of question (and you can look up the site for similar answers).